# sublime automatically add line breaks and indents

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to automatically reformat javascript code with sublime?
E.g. if I get code like this

https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js

How can I copy this into sublime and automatically make it readable?

Answer (score 2):

There are several Javascript formatters available in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). For un-minifying JS, I either use [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) or [`JsFormat`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat), or both. Please note that HTML-CSS-JS Prettify requires Node.js on your system, while JsFormat is a standalone program. JsFormat is the suggested replacement for the tool you found at https://beautifier.io, which uses `js-beautify` - see [here](https://beautifier.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I just found

https://beautifier.io/

which solved my problem... sublime should provide such a tool

Comment: There are many in the package control that do exactly that.